# lm function/coefficients, for specific different time windows/events in one data frame R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lm, magrittr

I am conducting an event study with the market model: AR(i,t)=R(i,t) - ((alpha(i) + beta(i)*R(m,t)). I struggle with calculating the alpha(intercept) and beta(slope) estimators because of data format and filtering. This is what my data looks like at the moment:

```
    Date       ISIN             R  STOXX_Return     Rating_Change     Rating    
 9  2016-10-01 CH00  0.0175315633 -0.0003749766              0.00          A
10  2016-11-01 CH00 -0.0733760706 -0.0220566972              0.00          A
11  2016-12-01 CH00 -0.0107454123  0.0182991778              0.00          A
12  2017-01-01 CH00  0.0457420548  0.0641541456              1.90          A
...
21  2017-10-01 CH00  0.0250723834  0.0374169332              0.00          A
22  2017-11-01 CH00 -0.0780495570  0.0179348620              0.00          A
23  2017-12-01 CH00  0.0688209502 -0.0312226700              0.00          A
24  2018-01-01 CH00 -0.0064684781  0.0144049186             -0.90          A
..
74  2017-01-01 GB00  0.0409336446  0.0641541456              0.00         B+
75  2017-02-01 GB00  0.0056671717  0.0006470779              0.00         B+
76  2017-03-01 GB00  0.0028145957  0.0364348490              0.00         B+
77  2017-04-01 GB00  0.0366417787  0.0144673074              3.66         B+
...
```

There is an "event" if the Rating Change is non-zero (line 12, 24, 77).

What I need, is doing a regression with the lm() function for only the pre-event-windows (for instance lines 9:11, 21:23, 74:77 - which is -3:1 pre event).

However, there are several events per ISIN

- meaning I have to group by ISIN and by the event (non-zero rating change) and
- then do the regression with lm() (R ~ STOXX_Return) for each pre-event-window and each ISIN and
- save the values in columns next to the event and pre-event-window.

I did not manage to do it in a conditional for-loop or with magrittr/dplyr (or anything google-able :-) ). Nothing really worked out - I just do not know how to manage the "double-filter" for ISIN and event, with a following regression and the output of the coefficients.
Has anyone an approach how to solve this?

Thank you very much in advance for any support- very appreciated!

**Addition after response**

I tried the following way:

```
PRE-WINDOW
filter_lmco_pre_tmp1 <- within(data, {
  event_pre_window <- if_else(lag(Rating_Change!=0),1,0)
  event_pre_window <- ave(event_pre_window, lag(ISIN), FUN=cumsum)
})
    Date       ISIN          R STOXX_Return     Rating_Change     Rating event_pre_window
10  2016-11-01 CH00 -0.0733761   -0.0220567              0.00          A               NA
11  2016-12-01 CH00 -0.0107454    0.0182992              0.00          A                0
12  2017-01-01 CH00  0.0457421    0.0641541              1.90          A                0
13  2017-02-01 CH00  0.0208479    0.0006471              0.00          A                1
14  2017-03-01 CH00  0.0351640    0.0364348              0.00          A                1
22  2017-11-01 CH00 -0.0780496    0.0179349              0.00          A                1
23  2017-12-01 CH00  0.0688210   -0.0312227              0.00          A                1
24  2018-01-01 CH00 -0.0064685    0.0144049             -0.90          A                1
```

```
POST-WINDOW
filter_lmco_post_tmp1 <- within(data, {
  event_post_window <- if_else(Rating_Change !=0,1,0)
  event_post_window <- ave(event_post_window, ISIN, FUN=cumsum)
})
    Date       ISIN          R   STOXX_Return     Rating_Change     Rating event_post_window
10  2016-11-01 CH00 -0.0733761   -0.0220567              0.00          A                 0
11  2016-12-01 CH00 -0.0107454    0.0182992              0.00          A                 0
12  2017-01-01 CH00  0.0457421    0.0641541              1.90          A                 1
13  2017-02-01 CH00  0.0208479    0.0006471              0.00          A                 1
14  2017-03-01 CH00  0.0351640    0.0364348              0.00          A                 1
22  2017-11-01 CH00 -0.0780496    0.0179349              0.00          A                 1
23  2017-12-01 CH00  0.0688210   -0.0312227              0.00          A                 1
24  2018-01-01 CH00 -0.0064685    0.0144049             -0.90          A                 2
25  2018-02-01 CH00 -0.0997418    0.0119439              0.00          A                 2
```

You can see that if there is an event (line 12 or 24) the pre and post event IDs are not the same. The first event-id of pre window starts with 0 and of post window with 1. This is because I lagged the pre-events. However, if I do not lag, then the actual event is not included in the pre-event. So is there a way to get for both, the pre and post window an "ID" so that the matching afterwards is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning columns for the pre-windows with `cumsum`, `ifelse` and `ave`. Then call `by` (or `split`) to create a list of data frames for each ISIN and event pre-window. Finally, use `tail` to retrieve last 3 rows and pass into your modeling function. All handled in base R!

```
# CREATE EVENT PRE-WINDOW COLUMN
my_df <- within(my_df, {
    event_pre_window <- ifelse(Rating_change != 0, 1, 0)
    event_pre_window <- ave(event_pre_window, ISIN, FUN=cumsum)
    event_pre_window <- ifelse(Rating_Change != 0, event_pre_window-1, event_pre_window)
})

# DEFINE FUNCTION TO PROCESS SINGLE DATAFRAME
my_lm_model <- function(df) {
   # ... code to run lm and return results on each pre-window
}

# SPLIT DF BY ISIN AND PRE-WINDOWS
# CALL ABOVE FUNCTION ON EACH TAILED SUBSET
pre_windows_lm_results_list <- by(
    my_df,
    my_df[c("ISIN", "event_pre_window")], 
    function(sub)  my_lm_model(tail(sub, 3))
)
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thank you so much, this approach with the additional pre-window-IDs really was the game changer for me. Generally, I have now the structure I needed,  however, for applying my calculations afterwards (for the event study itself), I also need post-window-IDs of my events (which should be the same as the pre-window-IDs) - for the rematching at the end. I edited my post in order to explain what I need. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Try adding another `ifelse` at end to change the actual event to include pre or post windows. See edit.